# Jquery validation checkbox implies another question must be answered

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

What kind of jquery validation rule would you use to specify that if a particular checkbox (say, for example, checkbox1) is checked, a particular textarea (say, for example, textbox1) must have a non-blank value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` rule can be used with a dependency expression, [as outlined in the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression):

```
$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        txtarea: {
            required: "#check1:checked"
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/y8qhv/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add/remove a "required" class depending on if it is checked.

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
if($(this).prop('checked')){
 $('#textbox1').addClass('required');
}else{
 $('#textbox1').removeClass('required');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plugin called [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) and when the checkbox is clicked I'd then add a "required" class to the control using addClass("required").

then when i use form.validate() it should check automatically for me and show the required text

so to validate;

```
$($("form").first()).validate();
```

Comment: I thought by adding the validate plugin tag it would be obvious I'm already using the same validate plugin you suggested. But maybe I'm still a bit of a stack overflow n00b? The part I'm having trouble with is not how to validate the form, but how to make dependent rules

Comment: @Jessica: You're correct, including [tag:jquery-validate] indicates you are using this plugin.